# How to create tabbed, text-bubble, effect

Tags: jquery, user-input, gui

You know what I am talking about: Where some websites have a text area (for tagging, or for mass emailing), you type something and when you press enter a bubble appears to wrap your text into a single unit, with a small 'x' on the side which when clicked will erase the bubble and all its contents.

What is that bubble effect called? Can someone point me in the right direction on how it can be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call it tag suggestion. This jquery plugin does sort of what you want http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-it/ but with no actual bubble. You can probably do the bubble with some CSS styling to get rounded corners.